# MySQL Hash Indexes for Optimization

Tags: mysql, hash, indexing, b-tree

So maybe this is noob, but I'm messing with a couple tables.

I have TABLE A roughly 45,000 records

I have TABLE B roughly 1.5 million records

I have a query:

```
update
    schema1.tablea a
    inner join (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            ID, Lookup,
            IDpart1, IDpart2
        FROM
            schema1.tableb
        WHERE
            IDpart1 is not NULL
        AND
            Lookup is not NULL
        ORDER BY
            ID,Lookup
    ) b Using(ID,Lookup)
set 
    a.Elg_IDpart1 = b.IDpart1, 
    a.Elg_IDpart2 = b.IDpart2
where
    a.ID is NOT NULL
AND
    a.Elg_IDpart1 is NULL
```

So I am forcing the index on ID, Lookup. Each table does have a index on those columns as well but because of the sub-query I forced it.

It is taking FOR-EVER to run, and it really should take, i'd imagine under 5 minutes...

My questions are in regards to the indexes, not the query.

I know that you can't use hash index in ordered index.

I currently have indexes on both ID, Lookup sperately, and as one index, and it is a B-Tree index. Based on my `WHERE` Clause, does a hash index fit for as an optimization technique??

Can I have a single hash index, and the rest of the indexes b B-tree index?

This is not a primary key field.

I would post my explain but i changed the name on these tables. Basically it is using the index only for ID...instead of using the ID, Lookup, I would like to force it to use both, or at least turn it into a different kind of index and see if that helps?

Now I know MySQL is smart enough to determine which index is most appropriate, so is that what it's doing?
The Lookup field maps the first and second part of the ID...

Any help or insight on this is appreciated.

---

#### UPDATE

An `EXPLAIN` on the `UPDATE` after I took out sub-query.

```
+----+-------------+-------+------+-----------------------------+--------------+---------+-------------------+-------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type |        possible_keys        |     key      | key_len |        ref        | rows  |    Extra    |
+----+-------------+-------+------+-----------------------------+--------------+---------+-------------------+-------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | m     | ALL  | Lookup_Idx,ID_Idx,ID_Lookup |              |         |                   | 44023 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | c     | ref  | ID_LookupIdx                | ID_LookupIdx |       5 | schema1.tableb.ID |     4 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+------+-----------------------------+--------------+---------+-------------------+-------+-------------+
```

`tablea` relevant indexes:

- `ID_LookupIdx (ID, Lookup)`

`tableb` relevant indexes:

- `ID (ID)`
- `Lookup_Idx (Lookup)`
- `ID_Lookup_Idx (ID, Lookup)`

All of the indexes are normal B-trees.

Comment: In your `a inner join ... b`, shouldn't you have some relation between a and b ? Seems very much like you're creating a cartesian product here, which would explain the "for-ever" very well. No need to fiddle with index types imo.

Comment: yea, USING (ID, Lookup)

Comment: Are you sure that you haven't muddled up `tablea` and `tableb` somewhere?  The query plan shows a full table scan on `m` involving ~45,000 rows (which you said was the size of `tablea`)--but the `possible_keys` align to those you have given for `tableb` and the `ref` used in table `c` also appears to from `tableb`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Firstly, to deal with the specific questions that you raise:

1. > I currently have indexes on both ID, Lookup sperately, and as one index, and it is a B-Tree index. Based on my `WHERE` Clause, does a hash index fit for as an optimization technique??

   As documented under [`CREATE INDEX` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/create-index.html):

   > ```
   > +----------------+--------------------------------+
   > | Storage Engine |    Permissible Index Types     |
   > +----------------+--------------------------------+
   > | MyISAM         | BTREE                          |
   > | InnoDB         | BTREE                          |
   > | MEMORY/HEAP    | HASH, BTREE                    |
   > | NDB            | BTREE, HASH (see note in text) |
   > +----------------+--------------------------------+
   > ```

   Therefore, before even considering `HASH` indexing, one should be aware that it is *only* available in the `MEMORY` and `NDB` storage engines: so may not even be an option to you.

   Furthermore, be aware that indexes on combinations of `ID` and `Lookup` alone may not be optimal, as your `WHERE` predicate also filters on `tablea.Elg_IDpart1` and `tableb.IDpart1`—you may benefit from indexing on those columns too.
2. > Can I have a single hash index, and the rest of the indexes b B-tree index?

   Provided that the desired index types are supported by the storage engine, you can mix them as you see fit.
3. > instead of using the ID, Lookup, I would like to force it to use both, or at least turn it into a different kind of index and see if that helps?

   You could use an [index hint](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/index-hints.html) to force MySQL to use different indexes to those that the optimiser would otherwise have selected.
4. > Now I know MySQL is smart enough to determine which index is most appropriate, so is that what it's doing?

   It is *usually* smart enough, but not always.  In this case, however, it has probably determined that the cardinality of the indexes is such that it is better to use those that it has chosen.

---

Now, depending on the version of MySQL that you are using, tables derived from subqueries may not have any indexes upon them that can be used for further processing: consequently the join with `b` may require a full scan of that derived table (there's insufficient information in your question to determine exactly how much of a problem this might be, but  `schema1.tableb` having 1.5 million records suggests it could be a significant factor).

See [Subquery Optimization](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/subquery-optimization.html) for more information.

One should therefore try to avoid using derived tables if at all possible.  In this case, there does not appear to be any purpose to your derived table as one could simply join `schema1.tablea` and `schema1.tableb` directly:

```
UPDATE   schema1.tablea a
    JOIN schema1.tableb b USING (ID, Lookup)
SET      a.Elg_IDpart1 = b.IDpart1, 
         a.Elg_IDpart2 = b.IDpart2
WHERE    a.Elg_IDpart1 IS     NULL
     AND a.ID          IS NOT NULL
     AND b.IDpart1     IS NOT NULL
     AND b.Lookup      IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY ID, Lookup
```

The only thing that has been lost is the filter for `DISTINCT` records, but duplicate records will simply (attempt to) overwrite updated values with those same values again—which will have no effect, but may have proved very costly (especially with so many records in that table).

The use of `ORDER BY` in the derived table was pointless as it could not be relied upon to achieve any particular order to the `UPDATE`, whereas in this revised version it will ensure that any updates that overwrite previous ones take place in the specified order: but is that necessary?  Perhaps it can be removed and save on any sorting operation.

One should check the predicates in the `WHERE` clause: are they all necessary (the `NOT NULL` checks on `a.ID` and `b.Lookup`, for example, are superfluous given that any such `NULL` records will be eliminated by the `JOIN` predicate)?

Altogether, this leaves us with:

```
UPDATE   schema1.tablea a
    JOIN schema1.tableb b USING (ID, Lookup)
SET      a.Elg_IDpart1 = b.IDpart1, 
         a.Elg_IDpart2 = b.IDpart2
WHERE    a.Elg_IDpart1 IS     NULL
     AND b.IDpart1     IS NOT NULL
```

Only if performance is still unsatisfactory should one look further at the indexing.  Are relevant columns (i.e. those used in the `JOIN` and `WHERE` predicates) indexed? Are the indexes being selected for use by MySQL (bear in mind that it can only use *one* index per table for lookups: for testing both the `JOIN` predicate and the filter predicates: perhaps you need an appropriate composite index)?  Check the query execution plan by using `EXPLAIN` to investigate such issues further.

Comment: We have tried these already, you're correct tho. I appreciate your answer. Unfortunately the benefits from the simplified join are not noticeable. The query is taking over an hour to run, and after 5-10 minutes I'm usually cutting it off trying to improve it. That's why we are looking at indexing.

Comment: The query time - cost of derived table was not significant enough for us.

Comment: @Hituptony: Well, as stated in my final paragraph, one would need to check whether relevant columns are indexed and whether MySQL is selecting the correct indexes for use.  Your schema (i.e. output of the `SHOW CREATE TABLE schema1.tablea` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE schema1.tableb` commands) and query execution plan (i.e. output of the `EXPLAIN UPDATE ...` command), neither of which are given in your question, are essential to any further investigation.

Comment: Awesome answaer I appreciate it.

Comment: You know what we ended up NOT having to set the IDpart1, only setting the second part of it, and keeping the WHERE IDpart1 IS NULL in WHERE Clause it zipped through it. I am now more interested in the different storage types other than innodb and MyISAM as that's what I'm generally familiar with, thanks again.