# MySQL HASH index showing as BTREE for MyISAM database

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a `MyISAM` database and am trying to add a `HASH` index.  When I do and then look at the index type, it shows as `BTREE`.  From reading [MySQL Hash Indexes for Optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21049449/mysql-hash-indexes-for-optimization) it looks like `HASH` is not an option for `MyISAM`.

How do I alter my database to allow me to use the `HASH` index type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither MyISAM nor InnoDB support HASH indexes.
Only MEMORY and NDB storage engines support HASH indexes.

Here's a good summary of index types and the storage engines that support them: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/storage-engine-index-types/

Why do you want a hash index type so much? What are you trying to achieve that a hash index seems like the only solution? If you edit your question above with a description of what you're trying to do, I'll try to give some suggestions.